# Simplifying expression of mean value of number of hearts when drawing 5 from a deck

Tags: expected-value, card-games

Draw 5 cards from a deck of 32 cards (8 of each suit). $X$ counts the number of hearts.

For $k\in\lbrace 0,...,5\rbrace $ I have $P(X=k)=\frac{C_8^k C_{24}^{5-k}}{C_{32}^5}$.

I'm supposed to "calculate" $E(X)$. I really can't see what more I can do than write it from the very definition : $E(X)=\Sigma_{k=0}^5k\frac{C_8^k C_{24}^{5-k}}{C_{32}^5}$

Does this turn out to have a simpler expression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected number of hearts must equal the expected number of any other suit.

The sum of the expected numbers for all 4 suits must equal the number of  cards chosen i.e. 5.

The expected number of hearts therefore equals $\frac{5}{4}.$

Answer (score 0):

This is a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), whose expected value (mean) is:
$$\mathbb E(X)=n\cdot \frac{K}{N}=5\cdot \frac8{32}=1.25.$$
WA [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28binom%288%2Ck%29*binom%2824%2C5-k%29%2F%28binom%2832%2C5%29%29*k%2Ck%3D0..5%29) for the sum:
$$\mathbb E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^5 k\cdot \frac{{8\choose k}{24\choose 5-k}}{{32\choose 5}}=1.25.$$